# Text in the center of a line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to put a text in the center of a line, as you con see in the Image:

[Here the Image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX8S6.jpg)

I was trying, but with  it doesn't look good.

I'm using Bootstrap.

Do you have some idea?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your code? I suggest using jsfiddle.net

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try always to post your code and point why it did not worked and what you tried. See: [ask]

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry! Thanks, I know it now for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without masking** with background colors (i.e: white)
**but** using `:after` and `:before` pseudo elements **instead**:

```css
.line{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.line span{
  position:relative;
}
.line>span:after,
.line>span:before{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  width:99em;
  content:"";
  height:1px;
  background:#ddd;
}
.line>span:after { left:  110%; }
.line>span:before{ right: 110%; }
```

```html
Bla here
<p class="line"><span>User name</span></p>
and here
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```css
.line{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    background:white; /*It must have same color*/
}
.line .color{
    z-index:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:17px; /*If your font size is bigger, increase this value*/
    height:1px; /*Want a bolder line? Increase this value*/
    width:100%;
    background:gray; /*Want to change line color? Change it here*/
}
.line .text{
    z-index:1;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    background:white; /*It must have same color*/
    font-size:10px; /*Change font size*/
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
    <div class="color">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        oder
    </div>
</div>
```

Or try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mikegohome/w87bq5zd/)